# R Change type of nested list

Tags: r, list, class, recursion, nested

Updated:
I have a nested list and I am trying to change the class of the deepest levels of the nested list into a data frame. I don't want the higher levels in a data frame. I also have what I tried to make as a character vector in the list under sublist 1 and C. I want C to be a character vector but it keeps showing as 'list' when I do a typeof() or class() on it. I don't want C to be converted to a data frame; instead I want to leave it as is.

Here is some example list and my attempts, updated based on the helpful comments below:

```
a1 <- list(  sublist1 = list(A= list(sub1= c(10, 40), sub2 = c(15, 35)), B=list(sub1 = c(100, 400), sub2 = c(150, 350)), C =c("abc","def")),
             sublist2 = list(A= list(sub1= c(3, 4), sub2 = c(5, 6)), B=list(sub1 = c(7, 8), sub2 = c(9, 11)))
             )
b_char <- as.character(c('2,3'))
typeof(b_char)

changetypefun <- function(x){
  if (is.list(x)) lapply(x, changetypefun)
  #else if (!is.list(x)) x #here I try to say if its not a list just return what it is
  #else if (names(x) == 'C') # here I try to say if its the C object, return what it is.
  #else if (typeof(x) == 'character') x #here and the statements below I try to say if it is a character or not a list, return it
  #else if (class(x) == 'character') x
  #else if (is.atomic(x)) x 
  else if (!is.list(x['C'])) x lapply(a1[['C']],paste0('as.',class(b_char)))
  else as.data.frame(x)
}
result <- changetypefun(a1)
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple modification of the answer to your previous question does the trick here. Just change the `else x` clause to `else as.data.frame(x)` as so:

```r
a1 <- list(  sublist1 = list(A= list(sub1= c(10, 40), sub2 = c(15, 35)), B=list(sub1 = c(100, 400), sub2 = c(150, 350)), C =c("abc","def")),
             sublist2 = list(A= list(sub1= c(3, 4), sub2 = c(5, 6)), B=list(sub1 = c(7, 8), sub2 = c(9, 11)))
             )

changetypefun <- function(x){
  if (is.list(x)) {lapply(x, changetypefun)}
  else {
    if (is.character(x)) x
    else as.data.frame(x)
  }
}


changetypefun(a1)
```

Comment: thank you! i've been trying to undertand this function. can you translate it please? is it that 1) check if x is a list, 2) if so, go over x and apply the changefun, and 3) make into data frame? I dont get the "else" part....

Comment: Also, is there a way to pass in indices of the list (like number associated with the order of the sublist) that I want to convert into a dataframe, instead of all the sublists at the lowest level in my dataframe? I have a character vector in my data that I do not want to covert to a dataframe. So I wondering if I could create a condition for the second line of code that does a lookup to get the sublist names/order in the list, that I am interested in. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Adding onto @onyambu's explanation, the only way to escape the cycle of going through the lists is the else clause. If whatever you are looking at is not a list, you make it a dataframe and then exit that subset of the overall recursion loop. The easiest way to do what you want is probably to add an `else if (x == c("your custom character vector")) x` between the current if and else clauses. Notice how we only say `x`, not `as.data.frame(x)` towards the end to keep it as character. The `else` part means if it is not a list make it a dataframe. That only happens right before you exit.

Comment: thank you. I tried multiple ways--I updated my post above. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: I edited with some suggestions. Not sure what exactly you want, expected output for a1 would be helpful. Are you trying to flatten the list? Or just keep everything that is character as a vector? My solution does the latter. `purrr::flatten` does the first.

Comment: thank you! I think the best option for me is to extract the few list of lists that I have and and then adapt your code and apply it individually to each of my list of lists and then put them all back together. Thank you so much! I just have one more question...I'm trying to understand the logic still. Why is there an "else" as.data.frame? Don't I want it to look into the object and if its an object/character, then make it a dataframe? Why the else? Isn't the else going to make it into a dataframe if its not a list/character?

Comment: The else turns any branch of the recursion that is finished (is a vector no longer a list) into whatever is in that else clause. With this final answer, it checks to see if the vector is of character type. If so, it keeps it that way. Otherwise it turns the vector into a dataframe like you requested. That doesn't mean the whole list becomes a dataframe, just that innermost vector. The new dataframe is inside the list.

Comment: thank you so much. Is there a way to make not the innermost part into the dataframe, but the level above it?

Comment: Yes, just specify the vector you want to turn into a dataframe or keep a vector in an else if clause, within the last else. `else if (x == the vector) as.data.frame(x)` or so.

Comment: Thanks @dcsuka. No matter how I try, I get an error saying Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: This is a separate issue entirely, and no cause for it is present in the data you have shown me. There are plenty of available tutorials on how to convert characters to dates, you have to specify the format, etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I really appreciate all your help and I am very grateful; I've learned a lot here.

Comment: Of course, happy to help, Divs!

Answer (score 1):

With the **rrapply** package:

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(
  a1, 
  condition = is.atomic,
  f = as.data.frame
)
```

Comment: thank you!! can you please explain the logic? i'm not very familiar with this. what is this condition "is.atomic" and when we set f = as a data frame, why dont i see f in my environment?

Comment: @Divs There are two types of *vectors* in R: *atomic* vectors and *lists*. For example `c(2, 3)` is atomic. Usually we simply say "vector" for an atomic vector. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation! For the second question, I'm just not sure what "f = as.data.frame' does. Does it take this 'f' object and make it into a dataframe? If so, where is the f object in my workspace? many thanks!

Comment: @Divs `rrapply` recursively visits the elements of the nested list. When it finds one element satisfying the condition (is atomic), it applies the function `f` to this element.

Comment: thank you. How does it know that f is a function though?